# Using Twitter Typehead in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

In Index.cshtml, I have below code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
```

}

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/hogan-2.0.0.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Content/twitter/typeahead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('input.countries').typeahead({
           name: 'countries',
           local: ["Unites States", "Mexico", "Canada", "Cuba", "Guatemala"]

      });
 </script>


   <input class="countries" type="text" placeholder="Countries">
```

But there is no autocomplete suggestions....I just following first 2 steps in below link to do my task...

http://www.arungudelli.com/jquery/simple-jquery-autocomplete-search-tutorial/

Is there any help?

Comment: Does it work if you adjust based upon the comment on that page, about the typo? `input.countries` instead of `input.counties`?

Comment: Thanks Daniel...Definitely it is error...I corrected it. But still I have the same issue

Comment: Have you included the typeahead.js library file?  The tutorial doesn't mention it, but without it you won't get very far.

Comment: yes i added as below..I downloaded and put the script is right location:

<script src="../../Content/twitter/typeahead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @daniel, wud u plz give me the link to your bootstrap code...i will try to follow that..

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what is happening with your setup, but you shouldn't need to include typeahead.min.js and typeahead.js.  This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eLku/2/) simplifies what you have a little bit and works ok, so it should be a good place to start.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js"></script>

<input class="countries" type="text" placeholder="Countries">

<script type="text/javascript">
     $('input.countries').typeahead({
         name: 'countries',
         local: ["Unites States", "Mexico", "Canada", "Cuba", "Guatemala"]
     });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for introducing jsfiddle...I will explore further. Mostly I think I can solve the issue by experimenting with jsfiddle...

Comment: That is what I've found works best.  This library can be tough to use since it doesn't give you much to go with when it doesn't work the way you expect.